# Displaying Data From Firebase in iOS in 'Flashcards'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, tableview

I am developing an iOS app that displays certain words from a Firebase database. The difference, however, is that I want to display the search results in a 'Flashcard' style. I have attached an image to give you an idea of what I am trying to do. I also want it to act as a button (i.e perform some actions when tapped). It would be great if you could help me give me an idea about how I could get this done. Thanks a lot[image: ![This is what I want the search results to look like in a TableView possibly]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPiSn.png)

Comment: Stackoverflow is Q&A website not a code writing service. People tend to help with the progress you’ve already made. Show us your research.

Comment: @excitedmicrobe I am already able to display the words in a normal TableView but I can't figure out how to get them into this form. I am not asking for the code; just need help to get an idea about how to go about this.

Comment: Use a custom collection view. That’s the easiest way I’d go if the rows are generated randomly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.) Create a custom collection view. (Guide: https://medium.com/@michaelrojas_66889/how-to-make-a-custom-collection-view-cell-in-swift-6d5783ab7c1c)

2.)  Get started with Firebase. (How to get started: https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup)

3.) Setup everything you need for the collection view (Code)

4.) Retrieve values from Firebase. (https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write)

At least this is a start where you should begin. There is hundred of guides how to perform something like that, if you're googling the correct way. Once you get started, you should edit your post and ask more specific what you need help with and there will be a lot of people here who will help you out. But like someone said in the comments, it's not a code service. We're not building it for you. We're here to help you get in the right direction. (I know it's a pain in the beginning, and you will get confused a hundred of times. But that's the best way of learning.)

Good luck!